# Have you ever told your friend Peter that you wanted/want to go to the US for further education?

Tags: present-perfect, tense-agreement

You have been wanting to go to the US for further education. Your parents ask you:

> Have you ever told your friend Peter that you *wanted* to go to the US for further education?

> Have you ever told your friend Peter that you *want* to go to the US for further education?

Which is correct, wanted or want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Have you ever told your friend Peter that you wanted to go to the US
> for further education?
>
> Have you ever told your friend Peter that you want to go to the US for
> further education?

Both sentences are acceptable and common.  The first is probably the default way to say it, but the second makes clear that the "wanting" is still true in the present.  The first one does not make that claim, but leaves it open to context.  If, for example, the person was lying about wanting to go and or has changed their mind, the first sentence must be used.

> Have you ever felt you were different from others? Here it's not
> "are". Why? Is "are" fine?

In this sentence, using "were" clearly indicates that the speaker does not take a position on the truth of whether the person has ever really been different or not and refers to at least one occasion that could have happened any time in the past up to and including the present.  It is the same as saying: "Have you ever felt different from others?"  The difference may have been true in the past, but might not be true now.

Using "are" refers to present time and strongly implies that the difference being referenced would persist now or at least could still manifest itself at any time.  The reference to the present can also mean that the speaker asserts that there is a difference in the present and is just asking whether the addressee has ever felt this fact.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your explanation about the second sentence "have you ever felt you were different from others" is a little bit hard to understand. Could you please explanation it again?

Comment: ...refers to at least one occasion that could have happened .... *up to and including the present* . ...The difference may have been true in the past, but might not be true *now*.  You said that could have happened in the present, but meanwhile you said that might not be true "now". I don't quite get it.

Comment: *...persist now or at least could still manifest itself at any time.* What do you mean by "manifest itself at any time"? Do you mean manifest itself at any time *now or in the future*?

Comment: Sorry, for my lack of response.  If you say "have you ever felt you are different," this could mean the person might inwardly feel something is generally true now because of a past feeling. It might not always be outwardly manifest, but feeling that way even in once in the past might let the person think that it was true even today, even if they don't have the feeling now.  For example, "I once was felt afraid of a mouse, so now I think I'm a coward."  "I felt that way once, so I think I am different from others."  Does that help make my meaning clear?

Comment: If you say "Have you every felt that you were different from others," I could reply: "Yes, I used to be afraid of mice, but now I realize they can't hurt me and am fine now and no longer feel different from other people."  "I felt so once before, but no longer feel that way."  Because the questions is posed differently, I might answer differently, depending on the facts.

Answer (score 0):

> Have you ever told your friend Peter that you *want* to go to the US for further education?

This one. Because Present Perfect is present so there's no need to change "want" to "wanted" (a post form).

Comment: Thank you. I've heard this sentence from a cartoon movie: Have you ever felt you *were* diffrrent from others? Here it's not "are". Why? Is "are" fine?